# Rigorous procedure to prove or deny that inequality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

Let $N\in\mathbb{N}, N\ge 2$, let $p, q, s\in\mathbb{R}, s\in (0, 1)$, $1<q<p$ and $ps < N$.
I am trying to understand if the inequality
$$\frac{N-sp}{p-1} -(N-sq) +\frac{(N-sp)q}{p}>0$$
holds true.

I am trying for attempts, but I would like to find a rigorous procedure to obtain the desired result.

Could someone please help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not true: Try $s=\frac{1}{2}, q=2, p=10, N=6$. When $p$ is much larger than $q$, the $-(N-sq)$ term tends to be largest in magnitude.

Comment: As one way to simplify a bit, you can have one less variable by dividing the whole formula by $s$ and substituting $\frac{N}{s} = M$.

Comment: You should say more about what you've tried so that we know how to help. Otherwise it looks like you're just trying to cheat on homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this false?

Let $N=2, s=.09, q=1.1,$ and $p=20$.

From there, we see $\frac{N-sp}{p-1} = \frac{.2}{19}$, $N-sq = 1.901$, and $\frac{(N-sp)q}{p} = \frac{.22}{20}$.

In other words, you can make the middle term large while making the other two very small. This is possible by making $ps$ close to $N$ with $q$ still small.